# How to add two OrderedDict when key is same in both the OrderedDicts?

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

My first orderedDic is

```
OrderedDict([('3LEmxb4G9q5XnP9H5653ncMAbAgbDCzz8U', {'value': 0.5, 'valueSat': 50000000, 'txid': '4c4e1609392f6744cdf9ff57614eb5f6905f39baba8f046c3b3bd5a1e6b573c8'}), ('1ErSPkXKfdVgjseia1psccr6ng4zbyLNSE', {'value': 0.01349045, 'valueSat': 1349045, 'txid': '4c4e1609392f6744cdf9ff57614eb5f6905f39baba8f046c3b3bd5a1e6b573c8'})])
```

My second orderedDict is

```
OrderedDict([('3LEmxb4G9q5XnP9H5653ncMAbAgbDCzz8U', {'account_id': None, 'last_block': '', 'n_conf': 0, 'total_confirmations': 3}), ('1ErSPkXKfdVgjseia1psccr6ng4zbyLNSE', {'account_id': None, 'last_block': '', 'n_conf': 0, 'total_confirmations': 6})])
```

In the above two orderedDict, keys are same but values are different. How to merge the values of the same keys from both the orderedDicts and make one new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a= OrderedDict([('3LEmxb4G9q5XnP9H5653ncMAbAgbDCzz8U', {'value': 0.5, 'valueSat': 50000000, 'txid': '4c4e1609392f6744cdf9ff57614eb5f6905f39baba8f046c3b3bd5a1e6b573c8'}), ('1ErSPkXKfdVgjseia1psccr6ng4zbyLNSE', {'value': 0.01349045, 'valueSat': 1349045, 'txid': '4c4e1609392f6744cdf9ff57614eb5f6905f39baba8f046c3b3bd5a1e6b573c8'})])
b=OrderedDict([('3LEmxb4G9q5XnP9H5653ncMAbAgbDCzz8U', {'account_id': None, 'last_block': '', 'n_conf': 0, 'total_confirmations': 3}), ('1ErSPkXKfdVgjseia1psccr6ng4zbyLNSE', {'account_id': None, 'last_block': '', 'n_conf': 0, 'total_confirmations': 6})])
c=OrderedDict()

for key in a:
    temp=b[key]
    temp.update(a[key])
    c[key]=temp
print c
```

Your new dictionary is stored in c. Remember `.update()` updates the dictionary itself and returns `None`.

Comment: how can you generalize this solution to add N OrderedDict() ?